# Iterating over combinations of 4 timestamps from 2 timelines *efficiently*

Tags: combinatorics, enumeration, performance, combinatory-logic, time-series-analysis

I need help in finding a more performant algorithm.

I have two timelines in the form of two indexed lists where each element is a floating-point value that represents seconds. The values in each list are only growing with higher indices. Each list has about 2000 elements.

From every timeline, I take two indices and thus timestamps behind them. From these four timestamps, I calculate the ratio `distance_2 / distance_1`. Only ratios of 0.8 to 1.2 are valid (simplified; in reality, they can be configured).

---

I need an efficient algorithm that yields all possible combinations of timestamp choices that correlate to a valid ratio. To increase performance, there must be as few iterations as possible; e.g., by early abortion.

I currently use an algorithm, which isn't fast enough, that iterates in the following manner (as if DCBA would be a number with varying numbers of digits):

```
A|||B
C|||D

|A||B
C|||D

||A|B
C|||D

A||B|
C|||D

|A|B|
C|||D

A|B||
C|||D

A|||B
|C||D

|A||B
|C||D

...
```

The algorithm works in the following way:

- The advancement of a timestamp is always stopped (resetting it and advancing the next) when the distance between the timestamps on a timeline *in index steps* falls below a minimum (currently 1). This means, timestamps cannot cross over each other.
- Only when advancing timestamps from the first timeline, I check if the resulting ratio grew over the max of 1.2. If so, it is reset and the next is advanced.
- Only when it comes to advancing the least significant and most often advanced "digit" (A in above diagram), and only the first time in a continuous series of advancements of just this "digit", I proactively quick-advance it with bisection. This helps in the following case: The distance C--D became short, so that, when the less significant "digits" A and B are reset to their home positions, the ratio is initially smaller than the minimum of 0.8. More quickly overcoming the initial A positions, that, given the current state of C and D, all correlate with too small ratios, improves performance. But I don't see how this would be possible for every "digit" and as deterministically as the check against max, described in the previous point, which is just early abortion.

Comment: "*from these four timestamps, I calculate the ratio distance_2 / distance_1.*" - you mean the distance of the two timestamps on the first timeline vs the distance of the timestamps on the second timeline?

Comment: @Bergi: Yes. `distance_1` and `distance_2` are in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

## Algorithm

Step 1: Build the set of all possible distances from the first list, by enumerating all pairs of items from the first list and subtracting.  Sort this set, and call $A$ the result.

Step 2: Do the same for the second list, and call $B$ the result.

Step 3: Now, scan through these two sorted sets of distances, to find all pairs of distances that are in the range $0.8$ to $1.2$.  You can use a "two fingers and thumb" algorithm, with a thumb pointing at an element of $A$ (say its value is $a$), and two fingers pointing at the two elements of $B$ that form the range of values in $B$ that are between $0.8a$ to $1.2a$.  Next, advance the thumb forward by one element, to an element of value $a'$, and then you can advance the two fingers forward as much as needed to the new range, containing all values in $B$ that are between $0.8a'$ and $1.2a'$.  Continue.

Notice that your thumb and fingers only move left-to-right, and never go backwards.

In this case, since $1/0.8 \ne 1.2$, we should do this twice, once using a thumb on $A$ and two fingers on $B$, then once using a thumb on $B$ and two fingers on $A$.

## Running time analysis

If there are $n$ elements in each list, then step 1 can be done in $O(n^2 \log n)$ time, step 2 can be done in $O(n^2 \log n)$ time, and then the scanning process (to adjust the thumbs and fingers) in step 3 takes $O(n^2)$ time.  In addition, if there are $N$  4-tuples that should be output, then the process of outputting all the pairs of pairs in the appropriate range takes $O(N)$ time.

So, the total running time is $O(N + n^2 \log n)$, where $n$ is the length of each input list and $N$ is the length of the desired output.

Comment: And if you are willing to be extra fancy, you can get rid of the $N$ factor in the runtime by instead returning an iterable (with $O(N)$ iteration) data structure that contains the result of the "two fingers and thumb" algorithm by specifying which elements were added / removed each iteration.

Comment: I find step 1 to be too unregulated memory-wise. (Step 2 should be possible to do on the go. Or view 1 and 2 swapped.) 2000 items per list may be the *typical* case. `2000^2 / 2 × 8 float bytes` is 15 MiB. Should the input data contain 6000 items per list, we're already at 137 MiB. It would be be better if there was a way to do this live to a greater degree, keeping memory usage in check, while still reducing CPU load significantly.

Comment: I couldn't make much sense out of the fingers explanation. I think it'd help to speak in the context of timelines, distances and shifts and tell what intermediate results represent. • (Irritatingly, the other answer by @YvesDaoust was deleted without any hint as to why.)

Comment: @Enyium, I don't understand what "regulated" means.  Sorry that my explanation was not clear.  At the moment I lack inspiration how to explain it better.  Perhaps you can try to figure out how to do Step 3 by yourself?  Or maybe someone else will be able to offer a clearer explanation than I was able to?  My regrets.

Comment: @D.W.: By "too unregulated", I mean that memory requirements can grow rampantly, and there would need to be a plan against it other than printing, "Sorry, not enough memory." • I'm now on this track: Run through timeline A combinations. For each, run through possible timeline B starting positions; assume end to be after same distance percentage as on timeline A; correct to left or right with bisection to be in min-max-ratio range (should happen rarely); run through timeline B combinations with two loops towards min or max ratio by de- or increasing end, respectively.